# Write unicode file name in zip php (linux server)

Tags: php, linux, unicode, utf-8, zip

I use `ZipArchive` to zip all photos. The filename of original photo has character unicode. After all photos are compressed to a zip file, the filename of photo is changed to the other character.

For example original filename of photo is `"កែវ កេត_1429672475273.jpg"`, it will be `"сЮАсЯВсЮЬ сЮАсЯБсЮП_1429672475273.jpg"` in zip file.

This is my simple code :

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = 'photos.zip';
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
    exit("Cannot open <$filename>");
}
$teachers = array(
    'កែវ កេត_1429672475273.jpg',
    'ផាន់ ចាន់រស្មី_1429671047820.jpg',
    'ម៉ៅ ហៀង_1427422340782.jpg',
);
foreach ($teachers as $teacherFileName) {
    if (file_exists($teacherFileName) && is_file($teacherFileName)) {
        $zip->addFile($teacherFileName, 'teachers/' . $teacherFileName);
    }
}

$zip->addFromString('version.txt', date('YmdHis'));
$zip->close();
```

These are files with unicodes :

[image]

The file name is not the same characters unicode of original file:

[image]

My current server is Ubuntu 14.10 64bit (local machine) and Gentoo 64bit (real server). And the results are the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any question in your text but still will try to help why its so.

The `zip` format stores filenames as sequence of bytes.

it’s up to the zip handling tool how to interpret the names, i.e. in your case `nautilus`.